# Return 1st match from select case

Tags: sql-server

I have this MS-SQL function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetSource]
(
    @LandingPage varchar(MAX),
    @Referrer varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Source int

SELECT @Source = 
CASE 
WHEN @LandingPage LIKE '%gclid%' THEN 1 
WHEN @LandingPage LIKE '%blahblahblah%' THEN 2 
ELSE 0
END

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @Source

END
```

My question is, if the first case returns true, will @source return 1 even if subsequent cases also are true, or does it stop evaluating subsequent cases after the first match? Which is actually what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it will stop evaluating on the first true case. It is basically a cleaner `if...else if...else` style statement.

Comment: It will in your case. There are some exceptions where it evaluates later cases. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12945/3690 . It never returns later matching cases though as the result I f that's what you are really asking.

Comment: Yes as long as you do not have aggregates it will short circuit after finding a match.

Comment: Couldn't you have simply tested this out? 
`SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 WHEN 2=2 THEN 2 END`

Comment: @samyi. That would simply have proved that on at least some occasions it returns the first matching case. Not that it always does and is guaranteed too. This blog post has an example where that type of adhoc experimentation fails http://stackoverflow.com/q/3856863/73226. `case` is documented to behave consistently though.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily demonstrated by the following test:

```
DECLARE @Source int
DECLARE @LandingPage varchar(50)

SET @LandingPage = '5gclidasdfblahblahblah'

SELECT @Source = CASE 
                    WHEN @LandingPage LIKE '%gclid%' THEN 1
                    WHEN @LandingPage LIKE '%blahblahblah%' THEN 2
                    ELSE 0 
                    END

PRINT @Source --1
```

If I switch the order inside `@LandingPage`:

```
SET @LandingPage = '5blahblahblahasdfgclidasdf'

SELECT @Source = CASE 
                    WHEN @LandingPage LIKE '%gclid%' THEN 1
                    WHEN @LandingPage LIKE '%blahblahblah%' THEN 2
                    ELSE 0 
                    END

PRINT @Source --1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL case does not work like c/c++ where you need a break; the case will typically on the first match.

e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[whatstoog]
(
    @Name varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RetVal int

SELECT @RetVal = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @Name LIKE '%mo%' THEN 1 
        WHEN @Name LIKE '%lar%' THEN 2 
        WHEN @Name LIKE '%curly%' THEN 3 
    ELSE 0
END

RETURN @RetVal

END
```

At the same time, looking at your sample, you want to make certain that your % wildcard is avoids false positives, e.g:

If you run the above example:

SELECT dbo.whatstoog
  SELECT dbo.whatstoog

The results are 1, and 2 respectively, while

SELECT dbo.whatstoog also returns a 1 though you only intended to return 1 for moe.

PS. SQL Server supports regular expressions for LIKE which provides flexibility for more complex pattern matching.

--Edit

For accuracy, per Aaron's comment, the LIKE support of RegEx is not a textbook version of RegEx, but rather a similar and (relatively) limited implementation.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree that "SQL Server supports regular expressions for LIKE" - there are some expressions you can use that kind of work like regular expressions, but they are not regular expressions. To get RegEx in SQL Server you need to use CLR either directly (your own assembly or function) or indirectly (e.g. I think MDS ships with some RegEx functions that use CLR under the covers).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael McGriff for the good explanation. CASE also jumps out after the first true when different variables are being checked. For example I recently tested this code:

```
SELECT sortStr  = case
            when @code = 'AA' then '111'
            when @code = 'BB' then '222'
            when @othercode = 'CCC' then 'BAW '
            else '    ' 
   END
```

With @code='BB' and @othercode='CCC' I expected to see 'BAW', but instead it returned '222' because it jumped out after finding the first true.

Microsoft also documents this in their [CASE Transact-SQL page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx).